# Perform a task with all of the values in an array (Swift, Firebase)

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My situation is that I am creating a social media app, and I have an array of all of the people that the user is following. It looks like this:

```
let followingArray:[String] = ["user1Uid", "user2Uid", "user3Uid", "user4Uid"]
```

So, I want to perform a function using every userUid in the array to fetch their posts and display it onto a collectionView.

To give more context the function looks like this (the "userUid" is the element that I need to repeat with all of the userUid's using the array):

```
databaseRef.child("posts").child(userUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
// all of the code to get the posts information into another array to display on the collection view.

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I noticed that there is a method (forEach(_:)) But, I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something with every element in an array you can always use [forEach(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach). Try:

```
let followingArray:[String] = ["user1Uid", "user2Uid", "user3Uid", "user4Uid"]

for userID in followingArray {
    databaseRef.child("posts").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        // all of the code to get the posts information into another array to display on the collection view.
    }
}
```